# RxJs puzzle: Share a stream and conditionally retry it on new subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

**Context:**

Our web app can display **different help panels** at the same time.
When a panel require a given ID (for ex `help-id-1`), we reach an API, passing that ID and we get back the needed help.

Now, for some reasons we might be displaying **2 or more times the same help panel**. BUT, of course we don't want to hit the API more than once, for the same item, if fetched without error OR currently fetching.

Our "producer" gives us a cold stream to retrieve it:

```
const getHelpContentById = (id: string) => fromPromise(
  httpCallToGetHelpResultFromThirdLib(id)
).pipe(
  catchError(error => of({ status: 'ERROR', item: null, id })),
  // extracting the body of the response
  map(getHelpItemFromResponse),
  // wrapping the response into an object { status: 'SUCCES', item, id }
  map(item => setStatusOnHelpItem(item, id)),
  startWith({ status: 'LOADING', item: null, id }),
)
```

We start the stream with an object containing a status, and later we receive another object with a new status which is either `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`.

**The expected solution should:**
 - Fetch from the API on the first call for a given ID
 - If another subscription happens for the same ID before the previous one is done (status `LOADING`), it should get the same stream as the first call **without** fetching again the API
 - If a part of the app is displaying `help-id-1`, and fails, the stream should **not be closed** but rather `next` a value in it of type `{ status: 'ERROR', item: null, id }`, this way if another component tries to display again `help-id-1`, as the last status for that ID is `ERROR`, it should try to reach the API once again and both subscribers should receive live update `{ status: 'LOADING', item: null, id }` and then either error or success

**First try:**
Here's the first, non RxJs way of doing it I came up with:
*(code extracted from a service, which is a class)*

```
private helpItems: Map<
  string,
  { triggerNewFetchForItem: () => void; obs: Observable<HelpItemWithStatus> }
> = new Map();

private getFromCacheOrFetchHelpItem(id: string): Observable<HelpItemWithStatus> {
  let triggerNewFetchForItem$: BehaviorSubject<HelpItemWithStatus>;
  const idNotInCache = !this.helpItems.has(id);

  if (idNotInCache) {
    triggerNewFetchForItem$ = new BehaviorSubject<HelpItemWithStatus>(null);

    this.helpItems.set(id, {
      triggerNewFetchForItem: () => triggerNewFetchForItem$.next(null),
      obs: triggerNewFetchForItem$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => getHelpContentById(id)),
        shareReplay(1),
      ),
    });

    return this.helpItems.get(id).obs;
  } else {
    return this.helpItems.get(id).obs.pipe(
      tap(item => {
        if (item.status === ContentItemStatus.ERROR) {
          this.helpItems.get(id).triggerNewFetchForItem();
        }
      })
    );
  }
}

public getHelpItemById(id: string): Observable<HelpItemWithStatus> {
  return this.getFromCacheOrFetchHelpItem(id);
}
```

**Attempt from my co-worker:**

```
private getFromCacheOrFetchHelpItem4(id: string): Observable<HelpItemWithStatus> {
  let item = this.items.get(id);

  if (item && item.status !== ContentItemStatus.ERROR) {
    return of(item);
  }

  return getNewWrappedHelpItem(this.contentfulClient, id).pipe(
    tap(item => this.items.set(id, bs), 
    shareReplay(1)),
  )
}
```

Problems
 - if you subscribe to it once, and it ends up with error
 - you subscribe to it again from a new component
 - it does another fetch as expected BUT changes the references
 - the API call succeed, the second component is updated, the first one is not

**Conclusion:**
I'm sure that there's a way better Rx way of doing that, maybe even without relying a an "external cache" (the `Map` here). The best would be obviously to have a new operator for that :)

Answer (score 6):

I have basically this same scenario at work. I've been thinking about it for a while but finally decided to take a wack at it. My solution is a bit rough but I'll try to update the answer as I refine it. I'd love feedback on better ways to approach it.

### Problems/Steps

It is a rather complicated problem so I'll build it out step by step. We will start with an api method with no parameters for simplicity.

#### Sharing the stream so that multiple subscribers don't trigger multiple api requests

Just add the `share()` operator on the end to make it multi-cast.

```
return api().pipe(share());
```

#### Sharing the last response from the api

Just change `share()` to `shareReplay(1)`. The parameter indicates the number of previous responses to share. We only want the last one emitted so we put `1`.

Alternatively you could use the `tap` operator to keep a reference to the last emitted value and do `of(data)` instead of returning the stream if the last one was successful. This only applies if you never want to invoke the api again (like the OP talked about) but I'm keeping it generic to be flexible for other solutions.

```
return api().pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

#### Allow a new subscription to trigger a new api request if the last one was not successful

This is a doozy. It is easy to get the last value or even to rerun the stream for a new subscriber. But that doesn't benefit the previous subscribers. You might get a successful result but none of the previous subscribers will be notified. Essentially what you are asking for is to have your subject emit a new value when it has a new subscription. As far as I am aware, that isn't possible.

My work around was to setup my own subject that I could trigger each time someone requested the stream. It isn't the same thing but I think it is really what we want anyways. What we really want is some way to retry. If it isn't automated by using the `retryWhen` operator then we want some manual way like a new component loading. When a new component loads they would request the stream so this works find.

So we create a subject and call next in a timeout. I would much rather use a `ReplaySubject` or `BehaviorSubject` to avoid the timeout but I ran into issues with angular change detection when I did that (`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`). I'll need to look deeper into it.

Note that the `share` is on the outer stream. We want to share that rather than the inner one. Also note that I am using `switchMap` rather than `switchMapTo` since we want a new inner stream each time.

```
const trigger = new Subject<void>();
setTimeout(() => trigger.next());
return trigger.pipe(
  switchMap(() => api()),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Keep the stream alive after an error

The `catchError` operator lets you return an observable. Since we want that to be a message we just do `catchError(e => of(e))`. The problem is that this ends the stream. The fix is to put the catch inside of the `switchMap` so that the inner stream can die and the outer one can keep going.

```
return trigger.pipe(
  switchMap(() => api().pipe(
    catchError(err => of(err))
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Know the state of the api

For this we will create a generic response wrapper that has a type property. The possible values are 'FETCHING', 'SUCCESS', and 'FAILURE'. We will use the `startWith` operator to send the fetching notification as soon as the api call begins (hence why it is on the end).

```
return trigger.pipe(
  switchMap(() => api().pipe(
    map((data) => ({ state: 'SUCCESS', data })),
    catchError(err => of({ state: 'FAILURE', err })),
    startWith({ state: 'FETCHING' })
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Only allow one in-flight request at a time

Basically we want to not invoke the trigger if a request is in-flight. We could either do this with a flag or using the `distinct` operator with a trigger to reset it when the api call resolves. This second method is tricky since you would need a reference to the stream while constructing it. So we will just use a variable and could either wrap the `trigger.next()` in an if or put a filter on the stream. I'm going to do a filter.

```
private state: string;
...
return trigger.pipe(
  filter(() => this.state !== 'FETCHING'),
  switchMap(() => api().pipe(
    map((data) => ({ state: 'SUCCESS', data })),
    catchError(err => of({ state: 'FAILURE', err })),
    startWith({ state: 'FETCHING' }),
    tap(x => { this.state = x.state; })
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Only retry on error, not success

All you have to do for this is to not call the trigger. So just change the condition on the trigger to be when state is not initialized or 'FAILURE'.

```
...
filter(() => this.state == null || this.state === 'FAILURE'),
...
```

#### Share streams for the same parameter

You basically just need to hash the parameters and use that as a key for the map. See the full example below.

### Solution

Here is it all put together. I created a helper function that will generate an api method. The developer has to provide the api method and the hashing method for the parameters since that would be overly complicated to infer.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { tap, switchMap, map, startWith, catchError, shareReplay, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

// posible states of the api request
export enum ApiStateType {
  Fetching,
  Success,
  Failure
}

// wrapper for the api status messages
export interface ApiStatus<T> {
  state: ApiStateType;
  params: any[],
  data: T
}

// information related to a stream for a unique set of parameters
interface StreamConfig<T> {
  state: ApiStateType;
  trigger: Subject<void>;
  stream: Observable<ApiStatus<T>>;
}

export function generateCachedApi<T>(
  api: (...params) => Observable<T>,
  generateKey: (...params) => string
): (...params) => Observable<ApiStatus<T>> {
  const cache = new Map<string, StreamConfig<T>>();

  return (...params): Observable<ApiStatus<T>> => {
    const key = generateKey(...params);
    let config = cache.get(key);

    if (!config) {
      console.log(`created new stream (${key})`);
      config = <StreamConfig<T>> { trigger: new Subject<void>() };
      config.stream = config.trigger.pipe(
        filter(() => config.state == null || config.state === ApiStateType.Failure),
        switchMap(() => {
          return api(...params).pipe(
            map((data) => (<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Success, params, data })),
            catchError((data, source) => of(<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Failure, params, data })),
            startWith(<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Fetching, params }),
            tap(x => { config.state = x.state; })
          );
        }),
        tap(x => { console.log('PUBLISH', x)}),
        shareReplay(1),
      );
      cache.set(key, config);
    } else {
      console.log(`returned existing stream (${key})`);
    }
    setTimeout(() => { config.trigger.next() });
    return config.stream;
  }
}
```

Here is a running example I hacked together: https://stackblitz.com/edit/api-cache

> I'm sure that there's a way better Rx way of doing that, maybe even without relying a an "external cache" (the Map here). The best would be obviously to have a new operator for that :)

I created a `cacheMap` operator to try to do just that. I had a source that emitted the api parameters and the `cacheMap` operator would find or create the stream for the unique set of parameters and would return it `mergeMap` style. The problem is that every subscriber would now be subscribed to that inner observable. So you have to add a filter (see alt. solution below).

### Alternate Solution

Here is an alternate solution that I thought of. Instead of maintaining multiple streams you could have one primary stream and give it to subscribers with a filter.

The problem with a single stream is that the replay would apply to all parameters. So you either have to use replay with no buffer or manage replay on your own.

If you use replay with no buffer then it will replay everything from `FETCHING` through `SUCCESS` which may cause extra processing though it probably wont be noticeable to the user. Ideally we would have a `replayByKey` operator but I haven't got around to writing it. So for now I am just using a map. The issue with using the map is that we are still emitting the same value to the subscribers who already received it. So we add a `distinctUntilChanged` operator to the instance stream. Alternatively you could create the instance stream and then put a `takeUntil` on it with the trigger being the instance stream filtered for success and put on a `delay(0)` to allow the last value through the pipe before closing it. This would complete the stream which is OK since you never get a new value one it once you have a success. I went with distinct because it allows you to get a new value if you wanted to change the requirements for that.

We use a `mergeMap` instead of a `switchMap` since we can have concurrent in-flight requests for different parameters and we don't want to cancel requests for different parameters.

Here is the solution:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { tap, mergeMap, map, startWith, catchError, share, filter, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

// posible states of the api request
export enum ApiStateType {
  Fetching,
  Success,
  Failure
}

// wrapper for the api status messages
export interface ApiStatus<T> {
  state: ApiStateType;
  key: string;
  params: any[];
  data: T;
}

export function generateCachedApi<T>(
  api: (...params) => Observable<T>,
  generateKey: (...params) => string
): (...params) => Observable<ApiStatus<T>> {
  const trigger = new Subject<any[]>();
  const stateCache = new Map<string, ApiStatus<T>>();
  const stream = trigger.pipe(
    map<any[], [any[], string]>((params) => [ params, generateKey(...params) ]),
    tap(([_, key]) => {
      if (!stateCache.has(key)) {
        stateCache.set(key, <ApiStatus<T>> {})
      }
    }),
    mergeMap(([params, key]) => {
      const apiStatus = stateCache.get(key);
      if (apiStatus.state === ApiStateType.Fetching || apiStatus.state === ApiStateType.Success) {
        return of(apiStatus);
      }
      return api(...params).pipe(
        map((data) => (<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Success, key, params, data })),
        catchError((data, source) => of(<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Failure, key, params, data })),
        startWith(<ApiStatus<T>>{ state: ApiStateType.Fetching, key, params }),
        tap(state => { stateCache.set(key, state); })
      )
    }),
    tap(x => { console.log('PUBLISH', x)}),
    share()
  );

  return (...params): Observable<ApiStatus<T>> => {
    const key = generateKey(...params);
    const instanceStream = stream.pipe(
      filter((response) => response.key === key),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
    setTimeout(() => { trigger.next(params) });
    return instanceStream;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well first of all, thank you for this detailed answer! I really appreciate. I'll need to dig deeper in your answer when I get few minutes free and see if it's working for my use case. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Maxime OK, let me know if you have any questions or feedback. I added a variant solution this morning. This is something that I am working on for my own purposes as well.

Comment: Haha nice, I tried the same approach yesterday but didn't finish it... (the one stream approach). Except that I thought I'd then split it into multiple streams and subscribers could just subscribe to the stream they want. I don't know if it's feasible... About your last solution I'm not sure but do we have to know all the IDs we want to register beforehand? Because I wouldn't know that. I might just subscribe later to another ID.

Comment: @Maxime You don't have to know any ids beforehand for either solution. In fact you can use api methods with more parameters than just one (which added some complexity). Each call to the generated method will be filtered to one set of parameters (one id in your case) but it could easily be extended to accept more if that is what you want. Under the first example there is a stackblitz link if you want to play around with it to see how it works.

Comment: I couldn't really do much better. And I learned a thing or two from your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Let's separate our concerns and deal with them one at a time:

1. Transform emitted items into metadata of `{id, status, item}` with an initial value instead of allowing errors
   much like RxJS's [`materialize()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-materialize)
2. Cache items until a certain condition becomes true (like an error)
3. Subscribing to the right api response

#### 1. Transform to metadata

We'll make a higher-order function that takes your `getHelpContentById()` and returns an observable of metadata objects that first emits 'LOADING', then 'SUCCESS' or 'ERROR' depending on the response:

```
const toMeta = fetch => id =>
  fetch(id)
    .pipe(
      map(response => ({id, status: 'SUCCESS', item: response})),
      catchError(e => [{id, status: 'ERROR',   item: null}]),
      startWith(       {id, status: 'LOADING', item: null}),
    )
```

#### 2. Cache items until a condition (e.g. 'ERROR')

Let's keep the caching ignorant of:

- how to fetch data from the api
- how to determine if data needs to be uncached

Both bits of logic can be passed in as functions to our caching operator:

```
/**
 * `predicate` returns a boolean
 * `action`    returns an observable
 */
const cacheUntil = (predicate, action) => {
  const cache = new Map()

  // Use our predicate to check if we should uncache an item
  //
  const cacheUpdate = key => cachedValue => {
    if (predicate(cachedValue)) cache.delete(key)
  }

  // Prep an item, then cache it
  //
  const cache_set = key => {
    const out$ = action(key)   // fetching it in our case
      .pipe(
        tap(cacheUpdate(key)), // see cacheUpdate above this function
        shareReplay(1)         // make Observable returned from `action` 
                               // a Hot observable
                               // so that we don't fetch 
                               // on new subscriptions
      )
    cache.set(key, out$)
    return out$
  }

  // Glue it all together
  //
  return pipe(
    mergeMap(key => // flatten the cached Observable returned from `action()`
      cache.has(key)
        ? cache.get(key)
        : cache_set(key)
    )
  )
}

// make a stream of help ids to fetch from api
// that we can call `next(helpId)` on
const helpId$ = new Subject()

// use a higher-order function to make our apiCall
// return our metadata object of `{id, status, item}`
const help$ = helpId$.pipe(
  cacheUntil(hasMetaError, toMeta(getHelpContentById))
)
```

And the predicate for our first parameter, fairly self-explanatory:

```
const hasMetaError = meta => 
  meta.status === 'ERROR'
```

With that, we can push help ids through a subject and get an observable of cached api calls:

```
const helpIds$ = new Subject()

const help$ = helpId$.pipe(
  cacheUntil(hasMetaError, toMeta(apiCall$))
)

// When we need a panel...
//
const addPanel(panel, helpId) => {
  helpIds$.subscribe(data => panel.display(data))
  helpIds$.next('help-id-999')
}
```

#### 3. Subscribing to the right api response

But wait! Each panel is receiving every item in the cache through its subscription every time we `next(helpId)`.

So let's filter it.

```
const addPanel(panel, helpId) => {
  helpIds$
    .filter(meta => meta.id === helpId)
    .subscribe(data => panel.display(data))
  helpIds$.next('help-id-999')
}
```

That's it. Here's a running example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-cache-until

#### Reusability

By separating out the metadata part, the caching operator becomes more reusable for other circumstances:

```
type Porridge = {celsius: number}

const makePorridge = celsius => {
  console.log("Make porridge at " + celsius + " celcius") 
  return Observable.of({celsius})
}

const justRight = (p: Porridge) => p.celsius >= 60 && p.celsius <= 70

const porridge$ = new Subject<number>()
const cachedPorridge$ = porridge$.pipe(
  cacheUntil(justRight, makePorridge)
)

let temperature = 30
const addBear = () => {
  cachedPorridge$.subscribe(() => console.log('Add bear'))
  porridge$.next(temperature += 10)
}

for(var i = 10; i; i--) {
  addBear()
}
// between the 60˚ and 70˚ 
// `makePorridge` gets called for every new bear
// because Goldilocks keeps eating it all
```

Comment: What complexity are you talking about avoiding with `switchMap`? You are still using a `*Map` operator (`concatMap`) which creates an inner observable that if it fails and is caught will not kill the outer observable.

Comment: You probably want to switch `shareReplay(1)` to `share()`. With the replay a new panel is getting the last value which may not be relevant to it. Your real replay is in your cache.

Comment: @Clarence Lee, thanks :) I did have to think for 20mn about that because it feels both cool and... problematic but couldn't tell why. So I decided to dig into the code and made a stackblitz (easier to share/fork): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nvfvcg?file=cache-unless-error.ts

Few tweaks: I've also added a startWith because as explained I want to handle the loading status. And finally, I've added a setTimeout on both promises (resolve and reject).

Comment: Now, if you give a try by clicking quickly on the 3 buttons, you'll see that they are loaded one by one which is not ideal. It takes 6s to load the 3 of them (because of my 2s setTimeout), but I'd prefer to have them separated and it should take ~2s in this case. This solution needs a bit more work :)

Comment: @Maxime switch his `concatMap` to `mergeMap` to move the requests from serial to parallel.

Comment: Yep but if I do that the cache will not work as expected anymore because it's writing in cache only if success so if multiple requests are made at the same time for the same ID it'll trigger other fetch

Comment: (just gave a try on my repro stackbltiz and I can confirm that behavior)

Comment: Once your call succeed, all the subsequent ones will use the cache but in the meantime they do not

Comment: @bygrace You're right about the `switchMap`. It's not really any more complex than any other `*map` when I think about it. Somehow, `switchMap` just didn't feel as direct as a `concatMap`, which shot me in the foot as has been pointed out :) I'll have to re-read your two answers, and have another crack at fixing mine. Thank you and @Maxime for checking out my answer and the constructive comments!

Comment: No pb, eventually we'll end up with a nice solution by trying that hard  =P

Comment: Just found time for another attempt. Turned out nearly the same as what @bygrace has. But for my own needs, I pulled out the logic for fetching data, and determining when to purge cache, as well as keeping the `next` out of the operator instead of using a timeout. Thought I'd update the answer in case it helps anyone coming across this.